# Bing maps for Windows phone app

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I'm trying to build an app for WP8.1 in C#. I want to add the bing maps feature for my windows phone app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maps for Windows Phone 8.1 are built into the WP8.1 SDK. No need to add any nuget for WP. You can find them under the Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps namespace. Below are some links for ref:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/020f8f/windows-phone-8-1-map-control/

http://www.jayway.com/2014/04/18/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-maps/

You can add map in xaml using "using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps" namespace and then from code behind you can set location, icon, or other children.

Comment: Also, you will have to generate the Maps token and AppId to be able to distribute your application on the store, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn741528.aspx

Comment: @NicolasBoonaert I have completed the coding part. All I need is the Map Service Token. Is this the paid one. I have gone through the link which u have provided, but can you please elaborate?

Comment: You can create key from https://www.bingmapsportal.com. you can go for "Basic key" type, which is free, if cumulative billable transactions within any 12-month period is  not greater than 125,000. https://www.microsoft.com/maps/create-a-bing-maps-key.aspx will give more information about key types and as per your requirement you can create key.

Comment: No Nishi, you're wrong. Because the key required is not for Bing Maps plaform but for Here SDK since the control and data are using those services and platform (Distributed by Microsoft though). Check my previous link you will be able to understand how to get the key and you will find the link to the terms of use here: http://cmsresources.windowsphone.com/devcenter/en-us/legal/MSFT_Mapping_API_Terms.pdf

From : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207045%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_terms